# Adding amount in reports_report_product_sold_grid.xml magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3.2

i want to add amount field to reports_report_product_sold_grid.xml in magento 2.3.2. Can anybody help. This is the code i am currently added. but not working.

app\code\Magento\Reports\view\adminhtml\layout\reports_report_product_sold_grid.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.price_incl_tax" as="ordered_price_incl_tax">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Amount</argument>
                    <argument name="total" xsi:type="string">sum</argument>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">number</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">ordered_price_incl_tax</argument>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">ordered_price_incl_tax</argument>
                    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-price_incl_tax</argument>
                    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-price_incl_tax</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

vendor/magento/module-reports/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Sold/Collection.php

```
  public function addOrderedQty($from = '', $to = '')
{
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $orderTableAliasName = $connection->quoteIdentifier('order');

    $orderJoinCondition = [
        $orderTableAliasName . '.entity_id = order_items.order_id',
        $connection->quoteInto("{$orderTableAliasName}.state <> ?", \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED),
    ];

    if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
        $fieldName = $orderTableAliasName . '.created_at';
        $orderJoinCondition[] = $this->prepareBetweenSql($fieldName, $from, $to);
    }

    $this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
        ['order_items' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
        [
            'ordered_qty' => 'SUM(order_items.qty_ordered)',
            'order_items_name' => 'order_items.name',
            'order_items_sku' => 'order_items.sku',
            'order_items_price_incl_tax' => 'SUM(order_items.price_incl_tax)'
        ]
    )->joinInner(
        ['order' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
        implode(' AND ', $orderJoinCondition),
        []
    )->where(
        'order_items.parent_item_id IS NULL'
    )->group(
        'order_items.product_id'
    )->having(
        'SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > ?',
        0
    );
    return $this;
}
```

can you pls help

Answer (score 0):

My implementation for price field (Excl. Tax)
Collection.php
You should override vendor files to custom module.
Magento 2.3.4

```
<?php

namespace Stonewave\ProductsReportsOverrides\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

/**
 * Data collection.
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
{
    /**
     * Set Date range to collection.
     *
     * @param int $from
     * @param int $to
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDateRange($from, $to)
    {
        $this->_reset()->addAttributeToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addOrderedQty(
            $from,
            $to
        )->setOrder(
            'ordered_qty',
            self::SORT_ORDER_DESC
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add ordered qty's
     *
     * @param string $from
     * @param string $to
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addOrderedQty($from = '', $to = '')
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $orderTableAliasName = $connection->quoteIdentifier('order');

        $orderJoinCondition = [
            $orderTableAliasName . '.entity_id = order_items.order_id',
            $connection->quoteInto("{$orderTableAliasName}.state <> ?", \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED),
        ];

        if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
            $fieldName = $orderTableAliasName . '.created_at';
            $orderJoinCondition[] = $this->prepareBetweenSql($fieldName, $from, $to);
        }enter code here

        $this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
            ['order_items' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
            [
                'ordered_qty' => 'order_items.qty_ordered',
                'order_items_name' => 'order_items.name',
                'order_items_sku' => 'order_items.sku',
                'order_items_price' => 'order_items.price'
            ]
        )->joinInner(
            ['order' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
            implode(' AND ', $orderJoinCondition),
            []
        )->where(
            'order_items.parent_item_id IS NULL'
        )->having(
            'order_items.qty_ordered > ?',
            0
        )->columns(
            'SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) as ordered_qty'
        )->columns(
            'SUM(order_items.price) as order_items_price'
        )->group(
            'order_items.product_id'
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set store filter to collection
     *
     * @param array $storeIds
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
    {
        if ($storeIds) {
            $this->getSelect()->where('order_items.store_id IN (?)', (array)$storeIds);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set order
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param string $dir
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    {
        if (in_array($attribute, ['orders', 'ordered_qty'])) {
            $this->getSelect()->order($attribute . ' ' . $dir);
        } else {
            parent::setOrder($attribute, $dir);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return Select
     * @since 100.2.0
     */
    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $countSelect = clone parent::getSelectCountSql();

        $countSelect->reset(Select::COLUMNS);
        $countSelect->columns('COUNT(DISTINCT order_items.item_id)');

        return $countSelect;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare between sql
     *
     * @param string $fieldName Field name with table suffix ('created_at' or 'main_table.created_at')
     * @param string $from
     * @param string $to
     * @return string Formatted sql string
     */
    protected function prepareBetweenSql($fieldName, $from, $to)
    {
        return sprintf(
            '(%s BETWEEN %s AND %s)',
            $fieldName,
            $this->getConnection()->quote($from),
            $this->getConnection()->quote($to)
        );
    }
}
```